# Preload gif image with page navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, preload

> Hi everyone i need a preload gif but my scenario is that when i click
>   on the menu button for navigation to next page it should start until
>   the next page appear and it should be close after next page load. if
>   there is any plugin or any kind of code you guys can provide i will be
>   very thankful ...

This is the code i am using to display my preloader

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    $(window).load(function(){
      $('#myloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
       $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (explanation in the comments):

```
( function( $ ) {

    $( document ).ready( function() {

        // document is ready, hide loader, don't remove since we want it back later
        $( '#myloader' ).fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
            // show scrollbar <- flaw in design!
            $( 'body' ).css( { 'overflow' : 'visible' } );
        } );

        // when user clicks on a link with class hide-loader
        $( 'a.hide-loader' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
            // don't follow the link, we want an animation first
            event.preventDefault();

            // show loader again
            $( '#myloader' ).fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
                // follow the link
                window.location = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
            } );
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Are you sure you added jQuery before this script?

Comment: yeah @ron it's there

Comment: i have to made few chnages to make it work ... now it's working thanks @ron